Flutter - TextField Alignment in Row with other Widgets
The code is working well for the iOS and Android but it fails to align text field vertically in web browsers. What could be wrong?
iOS Output: iOS same in Android
Web Output: Web
Code:
return LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) {
          double parentHeight = constraints.maxHeight;
          return Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              InkWell(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                onTap: () {
                  if (int.parse(controller.text) > 0) {
                    updateValue((int.parse(controller.text) - 1));
                  }
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: parentHeight,
                  width: parentHeight,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: const Color(0xFFcc0000),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                  ),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.remove,
                      size: parentHeight * 0.8,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: parentHeight * 2,
                height: parentHeight,
                child: Focus(
                  onFocusChange: (hasFocus) {
                    if (!hasFocus) {
                      if (controller.text.isEmpty) {
                        setState(() {
                          controller.text = '0';
                          updateValue(0);
                        });
                      } else {
                        updateValue(int.parse(controller.text));
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  child: TextFormField(
                    expands: true,
                    minLines: null,
                    maxLines: null,
                    controller: controller,
                    enableInteractiveSelection: false,
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: parentHeight * 0.6,
                    ),
                    keyboardType: kIsWeb
                        ? const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
                            signed: false,
                            decimal: false,
                          )
                        : Platform.isIOS
                            ? const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
                                signed: true,
                                decimal: true,
                              )
                            : const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
                                signed: false,
                                decimal: false,
                              ),
                    cursorColor: const Color(0xffcc0000),
                    maxLength: 3,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      counterText: "",
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    ),
                    inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                      FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                      FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'[0-9]')),
                    ],
                    autocorrect: false,
                    textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.none,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      controller.text = value;
                    },
                    onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
                      if (controller.text.isEmpty) {
                        setState(() {
                          controller.text = '0';
                          updateValue(0);
                        });
                      } else {
                        updateValue(int.parse(controller.text));
                      }
                    },
                    onTap: () {
                      if (controller.text == '0') {
                        controller.text = '';
                      }
                    },
                    onEditingComplete: () {
                      if (controller.text.isEmpty) {
                        setState(() {
                          controller.text = '0';
                          updateValue(0);
                        });
                      } else {
                        updateValue(int.parse(controller.text));
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              InkWell(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                onTap: () {
                  updateValue((int.parse(controller.text) + 1));
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: parentHeight,
                  width: parentHeight,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: const Color(0xFFcc0000),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                  ),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.add,
                      size: parentHeight * 0.8,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );

maybe the expands property of field doesn't work for web? if you know alternative solutions, will be highly appreciated! Thanks

Might be worth trying with a fixed height for your input rather then the parent height.

Try to wrap that text field with Center widget.
that's because crossAxisAlignment.center of the row is applied to the SizedBox of that text field.
While this sized box has got a dynamic height, it's supposed to be bigger in web view which leads to putting text field in its top left corner.
So, Wrap the text field with center widget.

Still it's not working

@AbdullahSaeed what's the result of replacing that SizedBox by a Flexible or expanded widget, and use center widget also above the text fied

thanks, have a look on good-one-deals.vercel.app, it's almost there

@AbdullahSaeed does it work, if yes i will update.
